# Symfony2 Adding 3rd party Bundles to a Service Controller

Tags: symfony

I am looking to get some help on how to add a 3rd party bundle to an existing service controller, specifically KnpSnappyBundle https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle.

The bundle was installed with composer, and registerBundles() function in app/AppKernel.php was updated.

I am having trouble with passing the bundle to a service controller, via its constructor.

1: Unsure how to figure out the path to use

```
--SomeController.php file--
...
use Symfony\Component\???\???

class FormDataController
{
    ...
    private $pdf;
```

2: Also unsure how to figure out what the object type is named.

```
    public function __construct(..., KnpSnappyBundle? $pdf )
    {
        ...
        $this->pdf= $pdf;

        return $this;
    }
```

3: Then in the servives.yml file i add the following argument to the correct controller

```
- "@knp_snappy.pdf"
```

After doing the above, the controller should be able to do the following to access the bundles functions, correct?

```
$this->pdf->...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you doing this?

Quote:

> The bundle registers two services:
>
> - the knp_snappy.image service allows you to generate images;
> - the knp_snappy.pdf service allows you to generate pdf files.

Just access them like this (if you use standard Symfony controller):

```
$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->...;
$this->get('knp_snappy.image')->...;
```

**UPDATE:**

If you are injecting `knp_snappy.pdf` service into your custom service, you should use `Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\Snappy\LoggableGenerator` class.

```
--SomeController.php file--
...
use Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\Snappy\LoggableGenerator;

class FormDataController
{
    // ... //

    private $pdf;

    public function __construct(..., LoggableGenerator $pdf )
    {
        ...
        $this->pdf = $pdf;

        return $this;
    }

    // ... //

}
```

When you run `./app/console container:debug` command, it lists all available services and corresponding classes. Very helpful.

Comment: I am doing it because it is a service controller.  You can not do $this->get() in a service controller, it must be passed to it in its constructor.

Comment: @dmnptr great! but how should I set the `LoggableGenerar` argument in config.yml? It has it's own parameters in constructor and throws such an error: `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\Snappy\LoggableGenerator::__construct() must implement interface Knp\Snappy\GeneratorInterface, none given`

config.yml:

    `knp_snappy.pdf.class:
        class: Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\Snappy\LoggableGenerator
        arguments: [?what's here??]
    customer.view_handler.pdf:
        class: Lobster\MyBundle\View\PdfViewHandler
        arguments: ["@knp_snappy.pdf.class"]`